# Index of list within a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

So I'm writing a code that uses exact diagonalization to study the Lieb-Liniger model. The first step is building a numpy array containing lists that describe particle occupations. The array would look something like

```
array([[2, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 2, 0],
   [0, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 2]])
```

for the case of 2 particles in 3 modes. My question is, is it possible to get the index of a particular list in this array, similar to how you would get an index in a regular list with the index function. For instance, with a list of lists, A, i was able to use A.index(some_list_in_A) to get the index of that list, but I have tried using numpy.where(HS=[2,0,0]) to get the index of [2,0,0] (and so on), but to no avail. For large numbers of particles and modes, I'm looking for an efficient way to obtain these indices, and I figured using numpy arrays were quite efficient, but I have just hit this block and have not found a solution to it. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want efficient lookup, a dictionary is better than an array.

Comment: Do you actually want a (presumably 1D) array containing lists, as you keep saying in the text, or a 2D array, as your code shows?

Comment: Following up on jonrsharpe, if you actually _need_ this to be in an array (for compactness, or because you're going to be doing element-wise vectorized operations on it in between the lookups, etc.), if you can keep it sorted, you can still get very efficient lookup, just not quite as efficient as a dictionary. (For example, at 1M elements, a dict is 20x faster than a sorted array, while a sorted array is 50000x faster than an unsorted one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several ways of doing this lookup:

```
In [36]: A=np.array([[2,0,0],[1,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,2,0],[0,1,1],[0,0,2]])
In [37]: pattern = [0,2,0]

In [38]: np.where(np.all(pattern==A,1))  # Saullo's where
Out[38]: (array([3]),)

In [39]: A.tolist().index(pattern)  # your list find
Out[39]: 3

In [40]: D={tuple(a):i for i,a in enumerate(A.tolist())}  # dictionary
In [41]: D[tuple(pattern)]
Out[41]: 3
```

I am using tuples as the dictionary keys - a tuple is an immutable list.

For this small size, the dictionary approach is fastest, especially if the dictionary can be built once and used repeatedly.  Even if constructed on the fly it is faster than the `np.where`.  But you should test it with more realistic sizes.

Python dictionaries are tuned for speed, since they are fundamental to the language's operation.

The pieces in the `np.where` are all fast, using compiled code.  But still, it has to compare all the elements of `A` with the `pattern`.  There's a lot more work than the dictionary hash lookup.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `np.where()` doing:

```
pattern = [2,0,0]
index = np.where(np.all(a==pattern, axis=1))[0]
```

Comment: Wow, heavy wizardry here, would you mind to explain why it works? +1

Comment: Try it piece by piece from inside out in an interactive shell.  In words - find row where all the boolean values (of `a==pattern`) are true.  `pattern` is broadcast, so `a==pattern` has the same size as `a`.

Comment: @heltonbiker as already mentioned, due to broadcasting rules when you do `a==pattern` you get a boolean array with the same shape of `a` and each column compared to each number of `pattern`, doing `np.all(..., axis=1)` will return `True` only when all columns are `True`.... giving you the right(s) match(es)... `np.where()` is only used to return the indices where we have `True` values...