# python finding index of an array within a list

Tags: python, numpy

What I have is a list where the elements are an array like this:

```
([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
```

What I want is to find the index of an element in this list, something like:

```
list.index([4,5,6]) #should return 1.
```

Problem is `numpy` array comparison throws up errors unless you put something like: `(A==B).all()`

But this comparison is *inside* the index function so i can't and don't really want to add the `all()` bit to the function. Is there an easier solution to this?

Comment: Make the question clearer.  Which things are Python lists, and which are `numpy` arrays?  They are not the same thing.  Don't mix-n-match. And this thing that you are looking for - will it always be a sublist or row (of an array)?

Comment: I answered this question a few months ago, with some time tests: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25944486/901925

Comment: i have had a look at that but for some reason, it doesn't work. the error i am getting is ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). I think this error has to do with the comparisons within the index function. I have tried converting between python lists and numpy arrays (in response to the question earlier, the place to search in is a list of array and the thing to search for is an array. But it doesn't matter which is which because i can convert between them. Problem is I still get that error when i convert all to lists.

Comment: That error means that one side or both of `a==b` is an numpy array, so the result is also an array.  But that expression occurs where Python expects a scalar boolean.  Test your code in small pieces.

Comment: List index expects a scalar value when it applies an `==` test.

Answer (score 8):

Your last error message indicates that you are still mixing lists and arrays.  I'll try to recreate the situation:

Make a list of lists.  Finding a sublist works just fine:

```
In [256]: ll=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
In [257]: ll.index([4,5,6])
Out[257]: 1
```

Make an array from it - it's 2d.

```
In [258]: la=np.array(ll)
In [259]: la
Out[259]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

It does not have an index method

```
In [260]: la.index([4,5,6])
...
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Make it a list - but we get your ValueError:

```
In [265]: list(la).index([4,5,6])
...
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

That's because `list(la)` returns a list of arrays, and arrays produce multiple values in `==` expressions:

```
In [266]: list(la)
Out[266]: [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6]), array([7, 8, 9])]
```

The correct way to produce a list from an array is `tolist`, which returns the original `ll` list of lists:

```
In [267]: la.tolist().index([4,5,6])
Out[267]: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting with a numpy array, you can get the result that you want by converting it to a list of lists before using the `index()` function, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
lst = [list(x) for x in arr]
print (lst.index([4,5,6]))
```

... which gives the expected output `1`.

Comment: `arr.tolist() == lst`